# LOAD DATA local INFILE cannot work on .net core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

The following query works in mysql.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TempTbl; 
create temporary table TempTbl like ACTIVITY; 

LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:\\test\\000000135_20190109133919.flat' 
INTO TABLE TempTbl COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But when I try to run in .net core, i get the following error. How can i solve?

```
var db = new RheEntities(Utils.GetAppSettingsByKey("ConnectionStrings:RheConnection"));
var query = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data/BulkInsertTemplate.sql"));
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
```

Exception Message:

```
Error during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

StackTrace:

```
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 80
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ReadFirstResultSetAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 302
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(MySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, ResultSetProtocol resultSetProtocol, IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 287
at MySqlConnector.Core.TextCommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(String commandText, MySqlParameterCollection parameterCollection, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\TextCommandExecutor.cs:line 37
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 261
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 62
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommand(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, RawSqlString sql, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlCommand(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, RawSqlString sql, Object[] parameters)
```

InnerException:

```
Use SourceStream or SslMode >= VerifyCA for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

Detail:

> .Net core 2.2
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.1
>
> Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 2.1.4
>
> MySqlConnector 0.47.1

Comment: Did you tried using `SslMode=VerifyCA` or `SslMode=VerifyFull` in the connection string? That message is a `NotSupportedException`, which triggered if SSL mode is not set to either `MySqlSslMode.VerifyCA` or `MySqlSslMode.VerifyFull`.

Comment: Yes @TetsuyaYamamoto, i got `Server does not support SSL` error. btw This code works on .net framework.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html

Comment: @Psi mysql config `loose-local-infile=1` . There is no problem on mysql side. Just not work on .net core, pomelo/mysqlConnector

Comment: I just wanted you to rule out security issues (that's where I directed you). I imagine that something similar could go on at the client side

Answer (score 4):

This is a security feature in MySqlConnector; see [issue 334](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/334). Since you are not connected to a verified host, MySqlConnector protects against an information disclosure vulnerability that could let a malicious server/proxy read any local file on your system.

From [Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html):

> There are two potential security issues with the LOCAL version of LOAD DATA:
>
> - The transfer of the file from the client host to the server host is initiated by the MySQL server. In theory, a patched server could be built that would tell the client program to transfer a file of the server's choosing rather than the file named by the client in the LOAD DATA statement. Such a server could access any file on the client host to which the client user has read access.

You can work around it by using the `MySqlBulkLoader` class instead of constructing the SQL yourself:

```cs
var loader = new MySqlBulkLoader(db.Database)
{
    FileName = "C:\\test\\000000135_20190109133919.flat",
    TableName = "TempTbl",
    FieldTerminator = ",",
    FieldQuotationCharacter = '"',
    NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1,
};
loader.Load();
```

Comment: P.S. Opened an issue to make this exception message clearer (sorry that it was confusing): https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/610

Answer (score -2):

Problem solved with `MySql.Data (8.0.15)`. I think there is a problem in (`Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 2.1.4` / `MySqlConnector 0.47.1`)